# check if swf file is being played on our own server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating games creating flash cc(as3). I just create game files and give it to other department and they upload it. I don't have any knowledge on php. My problem is if the file is uploaded to the website, it can be downloaded. My question is if it is possible to restrict it from downloading the file. If not, then restrict the file from being played on their own. I've came across a file which can be played on their server but if I download it and try to run on my desktop, it won't play. How to achieve something like that? I try to connect to server from the swf file before it can be played. If the file get proper key then only the file will play. But to do so I need user permission. Can it be done without user permission? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the *"running from"* location of your SWF by using [**`loaderInfo`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) and its `.url` method:

This example code below should give you a hint (uses `Switch`/`Case` instead of `If`/`Else`).

```
var domainURL : String = loaderInfo.url.split("/")[2]; //get URL from Browser's address bar

switch (domainURL)
{
    //# IF domainURL text is equal to test Case text
    case "www.yourdomain.com":
    case "www.yourotherdomain.com": //If you have more than one Case to test

    start_Game(); //Allow playing.
    break;

    //# ElSE
    default:
    show_Forbiden(); //Forbid playing.
    break;
}

////// Example supporting functions

function start_Game() : void
{
    //Logic for starting the game
}

function show_Forbiden() : void
{
    //Logic for forbidden (ie: display a warning message)
}
```

Comment: _"Put this into the root class"_ comes with no explanation of why it should be trusted to solve the issue. To a (possible) timeline coder saying _"root class"_ could mean nothing. I hope you don't mind the edit but hopefully it makes a more useful Answer to other future readers.

Comment: is it possible to restrict swf file from decompile without using third party software ?

Comment: @VC.One thanks. I always appreciate that kind of stuff.

Comment: @TheGunners no. SWF with its abccode/bytecode (compiled ActionScript) is an open format, and you will need an external tool to protect your script (I use http://www.kindi.com/ ) and another huge load of work to protect graphic resources.